# How to stop showing Chrome "password manager" in mobile keyboard?

Tags: google-chrome, frontend

I have developed one website which has a chat feature. Every time I click the text input I see the "key" / black bar from chrome which is used to store and configure passwords.

[image]

I have no idea why that bar is shown because the input type is text and not `password`

```
<input
     className="form-control"
     type="text"
    placeholder={i18n.msgInputPlaceholder}
     onKeyDown={onChatKeyDown}
     onChange={onMessageChange}
 />
```

This is very bad for the user experience and I want to get rid of the bar. You can see from my screenshoot that it takes a lot of space and blocks other content like the message that I want to be visible.
At best case, I want the keyboard to not show the black bar and push the other content up like it is doing, so the text input is still shown and also the remaining messages.

Any ideas how to do it?
Thanks in advance